# Nginx Server not responding

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-location

Nginx server is not responding periodically like every 30 minutes.

I have to reload it by nginx -s reload.

How to resolve the problem?

I can able to ping host. But unable to establish http request.

Comment: I have a feeling you are running this on Windows, can you confirm the OS?

Comment: Yes, I am running this on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: It's offtopic here. Please, ask questions about server administration on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after updating to latest version of nginx 1.2.3 to nginx/1.11.3